# Breaking wevtutil.exe cl loop

Tags: loops, batch-file

I am working on a batch program at the moment. I have been adding code snippets to ends of code blocks for it to go back to the main menu.

However, I reached this code snippet:

```
:EventLogs
cls
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('wevtutil.exe el') DO (call :EventLogsClearer2 "%%G")
:EventLogsClearer2
echo clearing %1
wevtutil.exe cl %1
goto :eof
```

When I attempted to add this code snippet in:

```
cls
echo Done!
echo.
timeout 5
goto Menu
```

It instantly went on to the above code snippet (the one directly above). It seems like the only thing that could follow this is

```
goto :eof
```

.

Anyone have ideas of how to break out of this loop?

P.S. I am quite new to batch (in fact, this is my first program)

Comment: You do not want to run the code after the label again, so you need to put a `goto :eof` or `exit` command before the label.

Comment: **In fac, this is my first program**. So this is your 3rd question on the same  program?

Comment: You can say that, yes.

Comment: @TKBuris I'm getting a little confused. Where did you add the code snippet?